# Align a floating lstlisting to the very top

Tags: floats, listings, captions

The following code does not align the lstlisting entirely to the top, but keeps some unwanted space between the page's top and the listing. How can I align the lstlisting to the very top?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{nice}{\noindent\colorbox{blue!10}{\hspace{1em}#1#2#3\hspace{1em}}}

\begin{document}

\lstdefinestyle{interfaces}{
  float,
  floatplacement=tbp
}

\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=nice,singlelinecheck=false,margin=3pt,font={bf,sf,footnotesize}}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=interfaces,caption={Caption.}]
interface Interface {
}
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Less code for showing the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[
        float % toggle here
        ]
    Hello world
    \end{lstlisting}
    \lipsum[1]  
\end{document}
```

Comment: I will add a more minimal example to your post. Just roll it back. But this is showing better the actual problem. Don't know how to fix that. sorry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a hint on page 38 of the manual for the [caption package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption):

> Please note that the listings package has its very own options for controlling the position and the skips of the caption: captionpos=, abovecaptionskip=, and belowcaptionskip=. (See listings documentation for details.)

Trial and error shows that if you add

```
\lstdefinestyle{interfaces}{
  float=tp,
  floatplacement=tbp,
  abovecaptionskip=-5pt
}
```

to your MWE then you get what (I think) you want:

[image]

For completeness, here is the full MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}


\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{nice}{\noindent\colorbox{blue!10}{\hspace{1em}#1#2#3\hspace{1em}}}

\begin{document}

\lstdefinestyle{interfaces}{
  float=tp,
  floatplacement=tbp,
  abovecaptionskip=-5pt
}

\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=nice,singlelinecheck=false,margin=3pt,
     font={bf,sf,footnotesize},skip=0pt}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=interfaces,caption={Caption.}]
interface Interface {
}
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```